# Can I use an operator as default function argument in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, closures, operators, default

I'm trying to use operator `>` as default function argument:

```
Playground execution failed: error: StackSorting.playground:27:63: 
error: expected expression after unary operator
func sort<T>(..., compare: (T, T) -> Bool = >) where T: Comparable { }
                                            ^
```

I solved it, but... Does somebody know a shorter way?

```
func sort<T>(..., compare: (T, T) -> Bool = { $0 > $1 }) where T: Comparable { }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the operator as default value for the parameter,
you only have to enclose it in parentheses:

```
func sort<T>(..., compare: (T, T) -> Bool = (>)) where T: Comparable { }
```